# How can I use functions and objects without require them in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, export

I have been studying NodeJS for about a year and today I found something strange for me. We all know that in order to use a module (function, object or variable) in another module we must export and import it except for the native modules like String, Number, Promise, etc. I installed an external package for unit testing called [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/).

The strange thing here is that I have created two test modules called: `logic.js` and `logic.test.js`, in none I have imported the Jest module, however I can access all its methods. Let's show some code:

**logic.js**

```
module.exports.add = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

**logic.test.js**

```
const lib = require('../logic')

test('Add - Should return the sum of two numbers', () => {
    const result = lib.add(1,3);
    expect(result).toBe(4);
});
```

As you can see in `logic.test.js` I have access to **`expect`** and **`test`** methods and i have not impoted nothing about Jest.

The questions here are:

- How is this posible?
- Its a good practice to do this with my modules

Comment: 1) `global`s 2) nope.

Comment: When I try this, I get `ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Comment: @ChrisG Have you installed Jest?  **npm install --save-dev jest**

Comment: @MarluanEspiritusantoGuerrero Of course.

Comment: You need to launch the jest test with the `jest` command line instead of the `node` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Jonas W* stated in the comments, they make use of the `global` variable that is common to all your application.

The use of the global variable is very simple

*test.js*

```
global.myObject = 'MyMan'
```

*app.js*

```
require('./test')

console.log(myObject)
```

Loading `app.js` will render `MyMan`

You might say that I actually import the test module and that Jest does not.

The thing is that you execute your node application using `node yourFile.js` but you instanciate your jests tests with the `jest` command line.

It's the `jest` command line that handles the binding between its framework (the `expect` and `test` methods.) and your script.

**Is it a good practice?**

I would say no. Except if you plan to make a library like Jest that have its own command line launcher and that you want to give tools like that to the users of your library.

The power of Node lives into the module organization, don't be afraid to use them.